# how to count the number of times the if statement is true in excel sheet using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

There is a excel sheet in which there is column of "Difference" and its value can be negative and positive. So, what I want to find is that suppose if the negative or positive value occurs 6 times continuously then count it as 1 and so on. 
End result that i want

```
Difference  count
12            
-134
34
234
22
23
43
566          1
-23
-21
-235
-58
-787
-34          2
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will work, here is a brief overview:

1) Loop over the Difference column.

2) If the number is positive, increment the plus_counter by 1 and set the minus counter to 0.

3) If the number is negative, increment the minus_counter by 1 and set the plus counter to 0.

4) If the value of any of these counters is equal to 6, change the value in the count column at the corresponding row (we keep track of the rows by storing them in the row_counter) to the value stored in answer_counter. Afterwards, increment the answer_counter by 1 and reset the plus and minus counters to 0.

N.B Since 0s are neither positive or negative, they are ignored.

```
import pandas as pd

diff = [
    12,
    -134,
    34,
    234,
    22,
    23,
    43,
    566,
    -23,
    -21,
    -235,
    -58,
    -787,
    -34,
    3
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(diff, columns = ['Difference'])
df['count'] = 0

plus_counter = 0
minus_counter = 0
row_counter = 0
answer_counter = 1

for each in df['Difference']:

    if each > 0:
        minus_counter = 0
        plus_counter += 1

        if plus_counter == 6:
            df['count'][row_counter] = answer_counter
            plus_counter = 0
            answer_counter += 1

    elif each < 0:
        plus_counter = 0
        minus_counter += 1

        if minus_counter == 6:
            df['count'][row_counter] = answer_counter
            minus_counter = 0
            answer_counter += 1

    row_counter += 1
```

Comment: yes this code works, thank you so much. Its just that i want to count the consecutive 
 6 positive or negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Not super clear on how do you want the output, but if you only want to know the number of times a value appears in its absolute form:

```
# Dummy df
gg = pd.DataFrame([12, -123, 34, 566, -34],columns=['difference'])

# Absolute values column
gg['abs_diff'] = abs(gg['difference'])

# Isolate duplicated rows
find_repeated_items = gg.groupby('abs_diff').count()
repeated_items = find_repeated_items[find_repeated_items['difference'] > 1]

# Add count column. Which will be the number of times the absolute value appears.
gg['count'] = 1

for duplicates in range(0, repeated_items.shape[0]):
    gg.loc[
        gg['abs_diff'] == repeated_items.iloc[duplicates].name, 'count'
    ] = repeated_items[
        repeated_items.index == repeated_items.iloc[duplicates].name
    ]['difference'].iloc[duplicates]
```

Output:

```
    difference  abs_diff    count
0       12         12         1
1       -123       123        1
2       34         34         2
3       566        566        1
4       -34        34         2
```